# Is there a way to force my own session ID in cakephp on its creation?

Tags: cakephp

I use database to store session data but session ID is stored in the cookie.
Is there a way to force CakePHP to use my own session_id logic?

I was looking into extending Session class but did not see any location where session ID is generated

Comment: Why do you need to do that in the first place? What exactly is the problem withe the default session ID's generated by PHP?

Comment: I wan't same session ID over different domains